# Indoor air conditioning unit makes whirring sound on startup

Tags: air-conditioning, blower, air, motor

I have a cooling only air conditioning unit that makes a whirring sound for a few minutes and then the sound stops.  It never made it before.  The air conditioning unit is a Lennox brand from the 70s.

Is it the blower motor that is failing or something else?

Comment: That's a classic, which unfortunately uses obsolete R22 freon.  Might be worth getting an energy monitor and see how much power it's taking... or find a SEER number on it if you can.  SEER is (very roughly) "BTUs per watt-hour".  With a little math you can compare that to modern units; even a basic Lennox is 15 SEER these days. Then you can see if the operating savings justify an upgrade.

Comment: Does the sound happen if just the fan selected or just with cooling selected?  Off hand it might be a bearing going, but that old, repair is almost not possible.  I have one almost as old and should get a new one, but I am lucky if I use mine for a day in ten years.  A fan is usually good enough.

Comment: Crip659 - Sounds happen in both settings, fan only & cooling selected.  So the bearing is part of the blower motor?  I thought I could just replace the air blower instead of the whole unit.

Comment: Harper - thanks for the knowledge.  Trying to refrain from replacing the whole unit in my condo because it’s an on the roof air conditioner and I would have to rent a crane.